# Rename an alphanumeric file

Tags: shell, rename, filenames

I have following files in a directory:

```
 GE.AARS_vs_Control16.txt
 GE.DHX30_vs_Control18.txt
 GE.DNAJC2_vs_Control18.txt
```

I would like to remove the `*_Control<numeric>` and replace it with `*_Others` such that the files will be renamed as

```
 GE.AARS_vs_Others.txt
 GE.DHX30_vs_Others.txt
 GE.DNAJC2_vs_Others.txt
```

Comment: Are they the _only_ files in the directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for file in /dir/*.txt; do
    mv "$file" "${file%_*}_Others.txt"
done
```

The `${file%_*}` is a form of shell parameter expansion that will remove everything from the last `_` and on.

Comment: Alternatively, `mv "$file" "${file/Control*.txt/Others.txt}`.

Comment: @DopeGhoti If assuming `bash` or some other shell that does things like that, yes.

Comment: Which is fair given the context of this particular answer, I would assert.

Answer (score 4):

Using the Perl `rename` tool, assuming you are located in the same directory as the files to rename:

```
rename 's/_Control1[68]/_Others/' GE.*_Control1[68].txt
```

Comment: Note: this is the `rename` written by Larry Wall (not any other tool called rename, there are others). It is written in purl (but don't let that put you off).

Answer (score 0):

If you like a little obfuscation, here's another way:

```
paste <(ls) <(ls | sed 's/_Control1[68]/Others') | sed 's/^/mv /' | bash
```

First, try running the pipeline without the bash :-) I'm assuming there are no other files in the directory. If there are, replace each `ls` with `ls *Controll1[68].txt` or some such, to limit the list.

> "I'd rather write programs that write programs than write programs" - Richard Sites

(I could have sworn that was Alan Perlis, but Google disagrees).