# Renaming directories with specific extensions

Tags: shell, directory, rename, mv

An extension to the previous question that I asked:
[Rename an alphanumeric file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/451375/rename-an-alphanumeric-file)

I have a directory that has subdirectories with an extension of *_upstream:

```
DHX30_vs_Control18.txt_events_without_u2af1_srsf2_altexons_upstream
GEMIN5_vs_Control19.txt_events_without_u2af1_srsf2_altexons_upstream
```

I want to rename them by removing everything after first '_' such that it becomes something like

```
DHX30
GEMIN5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for dir in ./*_*_upstream/
do 
  mv -- "$dir" "${dir%%_*}"
done
```

The above loop picks up every directory (the trailing slash does this) in the current directory that matches the pattern: "(something) underscore (something) underscore upstream". It then renames those directories by using parameter expansion to remove the longest match of: "underscore (anything)", which removes everything from-and-after the first underscore.

For example:

Setup:

```
mkdir DHX30_foo_upstream
mkdir GEMIN5_vs_Cblah_upstream
touch DX31_foo_upstream
```

Result:

```
$ tree
.
├── DHX30
├── DX31_foo_upstream
└── GEMIN5

2 directories, 1 file
```

Answer (score 2):

If on Linux:

```
rename -v 's/_.*//' *_upstream/
```

Comment: You are correct, added slash.